# R: a for statement wanted that allows for the use of values from each row

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm pretty new to R..

I'm reading in a file that looks like this:

```
1 2 1
1 4 2
1 6 4
```

and storing it in a matrix:

```
matrix <- read.delim("filename",...)
```

Does anyone know how to make a for statement that adds up the first and last numbers of one row per iteration ?

So the output would be:

```
2
3
5
```

Many thanks!

Edit: My bad, I should have made this more clear...
I'm actually more interested in an actual for-loop where I can use multiple values from any column on that specific row in each iteration. The adding up numbers was just an example. I'm actually planning on doing much more with those values (for more than 2 columns), and there are many rows.

So something in the lines of:

```
for (i in matrix_i) #where i means each row
{
#do something with column j and column x from row i, for example add them up
}
```

Comment: Take another look at David's answer - you can replace `x[1] + x[3]` with any combination of values and functions to create an arbitrarily complex function with any or all of the columns in your matrix. Without more detail, it still doesn't sound like you need a loop here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can use an apply function or a vectorized approach --- and if you can you *really* should, but you ask for how to do it in a for loop, so here's how to do that. (Let's call your matrix `m`.)

```
results <- numeric(nrow(m))
for (row in nrow(m)) {
    results[row] <- m[row, 1] + m[row, 3]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a vector out of this, it is simpler (and marginally computationally faster) to use [apply](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/base/html/apply.html) rather than a for statement. In this case,

```
sums = apply(m, 1, function(x) x[1] + x[3])
```

Also, you shouldn't call your variables "matrix" since that is the name of a built in function.

ETA: There is an even easier and computationally faster way. R lets you pull out columns and add them together (since they are vectors, they will get added elementwise):

```
sums = m[, 1] + m[, 3]
```

**m[, 1]** means the first column of the data.

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines should work rather efficiently (i.e. this is a vectorised approach):

```
m <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,4,6,1,2,4), 3, 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    1
# [2,]    1    4    2
# [3,]    1    6    4

v <- m[,1] + m[,3]
# [1] 2 3 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of those 100 ways to skin a cat questions. You are perhaps looking for the `rowSums` function, although you might also find many answers using the `apply` function.